# ASA 5585 Error ASA-MPC module found in wrong slot

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

We have following ASA 5585-x with two SSP-10 module and i am seeing following error when i plug my console on top (SSP-10) module.

```
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
**
**   *** ERROR *** ERROR *** ERROR *** ERROR *** ERROR ***
**
**      ----> ASA-MPC module found in wrong slot! <----
**
**  The ASA-MPC module is inserted in slot 1 and will not
**  function. Please insert the ASA-MPC module in slot 0.
**
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
```

But if i connect console on bottom SSP-10 module i am getting `ciscoasa>` shell so its good. what is the wrong in `slot1` and what is `ASA-MPC module`?

Here is the picture of LED indication

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPC means modules per chassis, and currently SSP-10 on slot 1 is not supporting, while in slot 0 SSP-10 module is supporting that is why you see console loging prompt.

Please see this link that can help you to understand the supported module on slot for ASA 5585-X series.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/compatibility/asamatrx.html#96172

Hope this answer can help you. Let me know if you have any other question.

Thanks for voting.

Comment: I check your URL and its all taking about `ASA version` so i am confused, does this means i can't put two `SSP-10` module in single chassis? or should i need to upgrade firmware?

Comment: If you look into the message in console when you do it for slot 1, it clearly shows, it shows wrong slot, as per my experience with cisco, it could be two reason, either that hardware is not supported on the slot or, software must be upgraded. And if you look some how deeper on the module page of the above url, you can get your answer.

Comment: You can also have a look on this url. https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_0xxAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=supported+module+in+each+slot+of+cisco+ASA+5585-X&source=bl&ots=WWwpc6t_q7&sig=3TbO3TnPOj8m2GOV-_A5umgcBFI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYqpj9munVAhXlwFQKHUYhCpYQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=supported%20module%20in%20each%20slot%20of%20cisco%20ASA%205585-X&f=false

Comment: I have noticed top module running `asa 8.4.1` and bottom module running on `asa 9.4.1`. if i want to upgrade 8.4.1 with 9.4.1 then should i move that module to slot0 and run upgrade?

Comment: Now, you got it your answer, please see first url, and follow this=> Current Models=>ASA 5585-X Modules=>Go to Section Dual ASA SSPs:- Dual ASA SSP-10s, where both SSPs IOS matching level is given. Now, if you want to upgrade the OS in module that is not detecting, so I think you first conenct that to slot 0, and then see if you get console conenction on that, before upgrading take a copy of the OS 9.4.1(existing OS in slot 0) through some TFTP/FTP/SCP server, then swap the module and upgarde the procedure. once upgraded both module, reload the chassis.

Comment: It works after upgrade from `8.x` to `9.x` Thanks for your help